# OSX Segmentation Fault 11 - Android

Tags: android, macos, segmentation-fault, unity-game-engine

When trying to run the Android SDK Manager in OSX, I am getting the following error:

> Segmentation Fault: 11

This was working until today. The only way I can get the Android SDK Manager to load is using sudo. I have tried changing the permissions of the folders and this has not helped.

Could someone point me in the right direction to get this sorted? I have also run DiskUtility and repaired permissions on the HDD.

Comment: I know nothing about the Android SDK Manager, but one thing that would be different when running under `sudo` would be which preferences and application support files get used. So, trying clearing those out. Or, as an experiment, try running it from a new user account as a test.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a go under a new account.

Answer (score 20):

If you have an external display try disconnecting it. I had the same problem until I disconnected my external display. Once the emulator is running you can reconnect it.

Comment: this is crazy, but was exactly what was happening to me.

Comment: I got this error after shutting down my emulator while it was on my external monitor. This answer worked perfectly!

Comment: This is the answer, I'll note that I only had to do it once. Subsequent emulator calls worked fine with the external monitor plugged in

Answer (score 1):

A segfault on launch could be because the SDK Manager script can't locate a working Java runtime. Note that a recent Mac OS X Java Update might have disabled your Java runtime. Open /Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences and make sure you have the runtimes enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue aswell - an alternative for the lazy folks is to simply edit the stored window position in the `emulator-user.ini` for that avd and set it to something positive, like this:

```
window.x = 1
window.y = 1
uuid = 1337313377559
```

You can find this file under `~/.android/avd/your_avd_name/emulator-user.ini`